# Python: urlretrieve PDF downloading

Tags: python, pdf, urllib2, urllib

I am using urllib's urlretrieve() function in Python in order to try to grab some pdf's from websites. It has (at least for me) stopped working and is downloading damaged data (15 KB instead of 164 KB).

I have tested this with several pdf's, all with no success (ie [random.pdf](http://www.mathworks.com/moler/random.pdf/)). I can't seem to get it to work, and I need to be able to download pdf's for the project I am working on.

Here is an example of the kind of code I am using to download the pdf's (and parse the text using [pdftotext.exe](http://www.foolabs.com/xpdf/download.html/)):

```
def get_html(url): # gets html of page from Internet
    import os
    import urllib2
    import urllib
    from subprocess import call
    f_name = url.split('/')[-2] # get file name (url must end with '/')
    try:
        if f_name.split('.')[-1] == 'pdf': # file type
            urllib.urlretrieve(url, os.getcwd() + '\\' + f_name)
            call([os.getcwd() + '\\pdftotext.exe', os.getcwd() + '\\' + f_name]) # use xpdf to output .txt file
            return open(os.getcwd() + '\\' + f_name.split('.')[0] + '.txt').read()
        else:
            return urllib2.urlopen(url).read()
    except:
        print 'bad link: ' + url    
        return ""
```

I am a novice programmer, so any input would be great! Thanks

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I would suggest trying out [requests](http://docs.python-requests.org/en/latest/).  It is a really nice library that hides all of the implementation behind a simple api.

```
>>> import requests
>>> req = requests.get("http://www.mathworks.com/moler/random.pdf")
>>> len(req.content)
167633
>>> req.headers
{'content-length': '167633', 'accept-ranges': 'bytes', 'server': 'Apache/2.2.3 (Red Hat) mod_jk/1.2.31 PHP/5.3.13 Phusion_Passenger/3.0.9 mod_perl/2.0.4 Perl/v5.8.8', 'last-modified': 'Fri, 15 Feb 2008 17:11:12 GMT', 'connection': 'keep-alive', 'etag': '"30863b-28ed1-446357e3d4c00"', 'date': 'Sun, 03 Feb 2013 05:53:21 GMT', 'content-type': 'application/pdf'}
```

By the way, the reason you are only getting a 15kb download is because your url is wrong.  It should be

```
http://www.mathworks.com/moler/random.pdf
```

But you are GETing

```
http://www.mathworks.com/moler/random.pdf/

>>> import requests
>>> c = requests.get("http://www.mathworks.com/moler/random.pdf/")
>>> len(c.content)
14390
```

Comment: Wow, that just seems weird, thanks for telling me about requests though.

Answer (score 2):

to write the file to disc:

```
myfile = open("out.pdf", "w")
myfile.write(req.content)
```

Comment: Trying to do this and all I get is an unreadable .pdf any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

Maybe its a bit late, but you could try this:
Just writing the contents to a new file and reading it using textract as doing so without it gave me unwanted text containing '#$'.

```
import requests
import textract
url = "The url which downloads the file"
response = requests.get(url)
with open('./document.pdf', 'wb') as fw:
    fw.write(response.content)
text = textract.process("./document.pdf")
print('Result: ', text)
```