# Can't download pdf file using python request

Tags: python, pdf, python-requests

I trying to download a file using python requests. I can download images but for the pdf file the content is empty.

```
class Scraper():
  def __init__(self, username=USERNAME, password=PASSWORD, 
               base_url=BASE_URL, login_url=LOGIN_URL, debug=False):
    self.session = session()
    self.authent()
    if debug:
      debug_http_request()

  def get(self, url, *arg, **kw):
    r = None
    for i in range(REPLAY_LIMIT):
      ld('getting %s (count %d)...' % (url, i))
      r = self.session.get(url, headers=FF_USER_AGENT, 
                           allow_redirects=False)
      ld('response code %d ' % r.status_code)
      if r.status_code in (200, 201):
        return r
      if r.status_code == 302 and r.url == BASE_URL:
        li("redirected to >> " + r.url)
        self.authent()
    return r

  def get_files_content(self, file_ids):
    for f in set(file_ids):
      url = ("very long url multiple lines string") % f
      file_result = self.get(url, stream=True)
      for block in file_result.iter_content(1024):
        if not block:
          break
        print block
      print "end of block"
```

When i'm trying to get the file content by:

```
ser = Scraper(debug=True)         
print ser.get_files_content([60857])
```

I get the following debug result:

```
reply: 'HTTP/1.1 200 OK\r\n'
header: Date: Fri, 27 Sep 2013 14:29:51 GMT
header: Server: Apache/2.2.16 (Debian)
header: X-Powered-By: PHP/5.3.18-1~dotdeb.0
header: Expires: Mon, 26 Jul 1997 05:00:00 GMT
header: Content-Transfer-Encoding: binary
header: Cache-control: private, must-revalidate
header: Pragma: no-cache
header: Content-Disposition: attachment; filename="the wanted file name";
header: Last-Modified: Fri, 27 Sep 2013 14:29:51 GMT
header: Content-Length: 0
header: Keep-Alive: timeout=15, max=96
header: Connection: Keep-Alive
header: Content-Type: application/pdf;
```

with no content in the response. 
FYI the below code works perfectly with other document like images. Thanks a lots.

Comment: `Content-Length: 0`. Can you send a request with your browser and make sure that your programatically generated request is similar?

Comment: Have you heard of [Scrapy](http://scrapy.org/) ? Anyway check the url : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14669827/python-urlretrieve-pdf-downloading

Comment: I saw this post but i thought that it's a way for the service to prevent from Scraping...

Comment: This doesn't really have anything to do with the fact that it's a PDF unless you're doing something weird specifically depending on the content-type, which I don't think you are. Like others have said it seems to be a problem on your server's end; I'm not sure mentioning "pdf" in the title of this question helps anything.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your server also thinks that the PDF file has zero length:

```
Content-Length: 0
```

Please debug the problem on your server. Perhaps the upload went wrong?